# Use wifi for internet without disconecting Eth0

Tags: wireless, ethernet

I'm running Ubuntu server 22.04 as a game server on a closed LAN.
`eth0` connects to the LAN with a fixed address assigned by the router, so multiple desktops can connect to it through the routers wifi.
the server was built with wifi enabled and connected through a phone hotspot.
I'm rural no landlines so the internet is only through two hotspots.
if I disconnect the `eth0` I have to install a monitor and keyboard to apt update through the wifi hotspot.
the server connects to the wifi hotspot fine it's connected and showing on the hotspot. but won't update through `apt` without disconnecting `eth0`. very annoying feature.
The hotspot wifi connection is set optional: true
so the system will boot with or without a wifi connection, but will never have a wired connection to the internet.
ive not found any solutions that don't require clicking on a tab that doesn't exist on the server.
I've enabled `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` with no success.

An installed simple solution of where the system determines where the default internet route is located or chosen would be a nice feature.

Is there a `.conf` file somewhere to edit to direct the system to get internet from the wifi when available?
or a simple fix.